# Potential reasons autocompleteclose event not available within a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm migrating some old code to a new site and there are lots of JS libraries being used so trying to pinpoint why this isn't working has been difficult. In short within a function I need this code to run:

```
    $(tabID).on( "autocompleteclose", function() {
        some_function(var1, var2, var3, var4, var5);
    });
```

These variables are only available within this function so that's why its being called within there.

If I define the event listener outside of the function in the main JS file, the event listener works. Overall, it appears to be some namespace issue as I've had issues getting other jQuery libraries working in this file when within functions, but in the main body of the file they work. I'm not terribly familiar with JS (and jQuery more specifically) so I'm looking at some starting points to figure out why it's not working.

As mentioneed above, the autocompleteclose event listener will work within the body of the JS file, but not within any functions. It appears to be a namespace issue with the JS libraries but I'm having trouble figuring out what are some other steps I can do to narrow down the cause of the error.

Comment: Those variables have to be visible in the context of that function call. If `some_function` is in a different context than the point where you make that jQuery `.on()` call, then it won't work.

Comment: @Pointy - Thanks, but the event isn't event being triggered so we're not getting to that point for that to be an issue. For some reason it's acting like there isn't an "autocompleteclose" event available. In the main body of the file the event listener works, but within any function it doesn't.

Comment: Well that doesn't make sense; jQuery cannot tell where the `.on()` call is coming from, and even if it could it doesn't care.

Comment: Yes, I am very confused. For example, in the main body of the file if I call something from the jQuery UI library - it works but if it's done within a function it doesn't. The only way to make it available to a function is to call a variable its assigned to. E.G. assign `$.ui` to `somevar` and then I can use it within that function - unfortunately way over my head here.

Comment: OK well what *exactly* do you mean by "var1, var2, var3" etc? Precisely what does the real code look like? Are your variables really called that?

Comment: @Pointy - Thanks for trying to help but what I ended up finding easier is moving the event listener to the main body of the file and refactoring it so I could access the data I needed outside of the function it was originally resting in.